# object Object in option

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I try to get a list of options, component Addreess returns `return adrress.features.find(place => place.id.match(region)).text`, in tag `<p></p>` I get actual String, but in options object Object. Why?

```
<select name="cities" id="cities">
          {data.allContentfulBlogPost.edges.map((edge) => {
            return (
              <Adrress x={edge.node.location.lon} y={edge.node.location.lat} />
            )
          }
          )}
     </select>
```

Output : `<select name="cities" id="cities">WarsawManchester</select>`

if I change to

```
<option value=""><Adrress x={edge.node.location.lon} y={edge.node.location.lat} /></option>
```

Output :

```
<select name="cities" id="cities">
  <option value="">[object Object]</option>
  <option value="">[object Object]</option>
</select>
```

Comment: An html `<option>` only accepts text (no child elements) and a `<select>` only accepts `<option>` or `<optgroup>`. Your markup is invalid

Comment: React 16.4 returns actual data to me, and I haven't object Object and string value is displayed

Comment: Well you need valid html structure to start with. Why are you trying to render a component inside `<option>` in the first place?

Answer (score 2):

`<option>` tag only accepts `string` value inside it. You are passing a JSX expression which is not a string and it is rendered as [object Object] in browser.

Comment: React 16.4 returns actual data, but I am using 16.8 and having this trouble...